# Showing the current progress

Tags: vb.net, listbox, progress-bar

I want to add the current progressbar value when it's not in the listbox. I want it to add a new item when the progressbar value changes.

Here is my code so far...  It just adds "0%" a million times..

```
 Dim PText As String = ProgressBar1.Value

 If Not PText = LB1.Items.ToString Then
    LB1.Items.Add("Uploaded " & PText & "%")
 End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Dim PText As String = String.Format("Uploaded {0}%",ProgressBar1.Value)

If Not LB1.Items.Contains(PText) Then LB1.Items.Add(PText)
```